# some of the toolbar menus are not seen in eclipse rcp application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When I launch rcp application some of the custom toolbar menus doesnot appear in my rcp application,if I change perspective then they appears.Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's hard to say with no additional information. How do you create those toolbar items? Using some contributor class or in plugin.xml, using menu contributions? With the second option, check, that you have defined them in the proper plugin.xml (the one, which defines your perspective, in which you want to actually see them).

Ensure, that there are handlers for your commands/actions in your perspective.

If you are using associations, ensure, that those are correct:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSetPartAssociations">
<actionSetPartAssociation targetID="YouractionSetId">
    <part id="YourPartId"/>
</actionSetPartAssociation>
```